# Web of trust and signature types? (sig1, sig2, etc)

Tags: gnupg, openpgp, web-of-trust

I have read about [The OpenPGP trust model](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/41208/what-is-the-exact-meaning-of-this-gpg-output-regarding-trust/41209#41209) but I don't see any mention of the [specific signature types](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/141501/what-is-the-meaning-of-gnupgs-list-sigs-output/141508#141508).  Are all signature types (`sig0` - `sig3`) treated the same by tools such as `gpg` or the [PGP Pathfinder](https://pgp.cs.uu.nl/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jens [has answered this quite well](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/141508/38316).  Basically, the signature levels are defined in the man page under `--ask-cert-level` and `--default-cert-level`.  `sig` refers to cert level 0, which "means you make no particular claims as to how carefully you verified the key."  This is the default when signing a key.  They run up through levels 1 and 2, to the highest level, `sig 3`, which "means you did extensive verification of the key."